# Magento 2 - How to change a label of a field in system.xml of an extension

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, system.xml

I purchased an extension and I want to change the label of a field in the admin to say 'Delivery Cut off Time' instead of 'Cut off Time'. This field is represented in the system.xml file of the extension

File: `Bss/OrderDeliveryDate/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="bss" translate="label" sortOrder="300">
            <label>Bss Commerce</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="orderdeliverydate" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Order Delivery Date</label>
            <tab>bss</tab>
            <resource>Bss_OrderDeliveryDate::config_orderdeliverydate</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>

                <field id="process_time" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Processing Time</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Delivery will be taken after(x) day(s) upon the date order(s) made.]]></comment>
                </field>

                <field id="cut_off_time" translate="label" type="time" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Cut Off Time</label>
                    <!-- <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model> -->
                    <comment><![CDATA[If customers place order after this time the date when orders made will be counted as the following day.]]></comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

I have gone ahead and created my own module to try to make this changes. `MyVendor_MyModule`. I created a `system.xml` file, but I am not sure what is the proper way to overwrite the label.

Comment: Just for title change we made custom module not best way. Custom Module use for enhance the magento functionality or extend functionality. Its simple change.

Reason: Magento will compile this module each time when user visit any page url  in store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do it via custom module then you just need to add following code in your namespace/modulename/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="orderdeliverydate" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
           <resource>Bss_OrderDeliveryDate::config_orderdeliverydate</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
               <field id="cut_off_time" translate="label" type="time" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Delivery Cut off Time</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: Just for title change we made custom module not best way. Custom Module use for enhance the magento functionality or extend functionality. Its simple change.

Reason: Magento will compile this module each time when user visit any page url  in store.

Comment: yeah, I agree  but she did not mentioned that she created module just for the label update. I just mentioned the method to update the label its the developer's wish to create individual module or merge this code to any of existing custom module.

Comment: Read Question carefully.

Comment: also its not good practice to directly update label in the existing plugin, because whenever the extension will be updated the changes will be overwritten, So we can make this change in any existing custom module

Comment: that's fine. I already said that I have mentioned the method to do the needful, and clearly mentioned that "if you want to do it via custom module" now its the existing custom module or new module its the developer's decision

Comment: Hi Ekta Puri and @Paarth, I am making more modifications to this extension so it is the reason why I created a custom module. I also don't think it is wise to modify the system.xml file just in case the module is updated.

Comment: Thanks Noemi. Can you vote me plz for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't Need to create custom module for just change the title of system configuration.System.xml used to edit the title only.